# Java server program is spitting out two U+FFFD characters when launched. Need help figuring out where it does this and why?

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I have built a Java server program that is part of an attendance tracker application. It takes in commands from client applications, and performs server functions connected to the database that we have set up. The issue is that once we launch our program, it autmomatically sends the client two U+FFFD characters (the diamond with the question mark symbol) at the beginning of the session, which thus breaks the clients code, and returns errors on their side. I cannot figure out where in the code this is happening, since what is printed to the command line is whats passed to the client. I don't even know where to begin looking. Here is the code for the main file, I'll upload the whole project on Github if needed. I know there's a lot of code there to look through but if anybody can even eyeball the issue right off the bat I'd be so happy. Thank you for the help!

Github: https://github.com/aepries/stacServ.git

```html
package stacserv;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class StacServ {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    
    public static JFrame mainFrame = null;
    public static JTextArea chatText = null;
    public static StringBuffer toAppend = new StringBuffer("");
    
   
    
    public static void initGUI(){
      JPanel chatPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      chatText = new JTextArea(20, 20);
      chatText.setLineWrap(true);
      chatText.setForeground(Color.blue);
      chatText.setFont(chatText.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
      
      JScrollPane chatTextPane = new JScrollPane(chatText,
      JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
      JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      
      
     
      chatPane.add(chatTextPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      chatPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

      // Set up the main pane
      JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      mainPane.add(chatPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // Set up the main frame
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Client Messages");
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPane);
      mainFrame.setSize(mainFrame.getPreferredSize());
      mainFrame.setLocation(300, 300);
      mainFrame.pack();
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    initGUI();
    ServerSocket m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);
    int id = 0;
    StacServ.chatText.append("Server is now running and listening on port 1025 " + "\n");
    while (true) {
        
      Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();
      ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
      cliThread.start();
     
      
      
      
    }
  }  
}



class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
  Socket clientSocket;
  int clientID = -1;
  String userName = null;
  boolean running = true;
  private MySQLAccess dbconnection;
  HashMap<Socket, Integer> connections = new HashMap<Socket, Integer>();
  public ArrayList<ClassData> queryResult = new ArrayList<ClassData>();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String commandName = null;
  String clientCommand = null;
  String restofString = null;
  String[] tokens = new String[2];
  
  
  ClientServiceThread(Socket s, Integer i) {
    
    
    clientSocket = s;
    clientID = i;
    
    connections.put(s, i);
    StacServ.chatText.append("Current Connections" + "\n");
    for(HashMap.Entry entry: connections.entrySet()){
        StacServ.chatText.append(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        
    }
  }
  
  
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try
       {   
            dbconnection = new MySQLAccess();
            dbconnection.connect("138.86.104.164","STACDB","SEClass","BearsRock");
       } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
       }
      
    System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + clientID + " : Address - "
        + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    StacServ.chatText.append("Accepted Client : ID - " + clientID + " : Address - "
        + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"\n");
    try {
      BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
     
      ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      
      while (running) {
        out.flush();
       
        in.mark(0);
        in.reset();
        clientCommand = in.readLine();
        
        
        try{
        if(clientCommand == null){
        } else {
            

            clientCommand = clientCommand.replace("\"", "");
            tokens = clientCommand.split(" ", 2);
            commandName = tokens[0];
            restofString = tokens[1];
            
            
          }
        }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //Handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
        
    
        
        if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGO")) {
          System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + clientID);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Stopping client thread for client : " + clientID+"\n");
          out.println("LOGO" + " logged out."+"\n");
          out.flush();
          running = false;
        }
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("REGU")){
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String uName = keys[0];
          String uPass = keys[1];
          String fName = keys[2];
          String lName = keys[3];
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to add client: " + fName + " " + lName);
          dbconnection.createUser(uName, uPass, fName, lName);
          out.println("REGR S");
          out.flush();
        }
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("CRCR")){
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String className = keys[0];
          String institution = keys[1];
          String startDate = keys[2];
          String endDate = keys[3];
          String ipAddress = keys[4];
          String meetDOW = keys[5];
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to add class: " + className);
          dbconnection.createClass(className, institution, startDate, endDate, ipAddress, meetDOW);
          out.println("CRER S" + className);
          out.flush();
        }
        
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("CSRC")){
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String className = keys[0];
          String institution = keys[1];
          
          if(institution == " "){
              institution = "%";
          }
          
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to find class: " + className +" "  + "\n");
          ResultSet rs = dbconnection.searchClasses(className, institution);
          //ResultSet rs = dbconnection.searchClasses(className, institution);
          
          while(rs.next()){
                    queryResult.add(new ClassData(rs.getString("classID"), rs.getString("className"), rs.getString("adminID"), rs.getString("institution"), rs.getString("startDate"), rs.getString("endDate"), rs.getString("PublicIPAddress")));
                    String ctClassID = rs.getString("classID");
                    String ctClassName = rs.getString("className");
                    String ctAdminID = rs.getString("adminID");
                    String ctinstitution = rs.getString("institution");
                    String ctstartDate = rs.getString("startDate");
                    String ctendDate = rs.getString("startDate");
                    String ctipAddress = rs.getString("endDate");
                    out.println("CDTR S" +  ctClassID + ctClassName + ctAdminID  + ctinstitution + ctstartDate + ctendDate + ctipAddress);
                    StacServ.chatText.append("CDTR S" + " "  +  ctClassID + " " + ctClassName + " " + ctAdminID + " "  + ctinstitution + " " + ctstartDate + " " + ctendDate + " " + ctipAddress + "\n");
                    
                    
                } 
        }
        
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("CTDL")){
          
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String classID = keys[0];
          int classId = Integer.parseInt(classID);
          
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          
          
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to find class with ID: " + classId + "\n");
          ResultSet rs = dbconnection.searchClasses(classId);
          
              
                while(rs.next()){
                    queryResult.add(new ClassData(rs.getString("classID"), rs.getString("className"), rs.getString("adminID"), rs.getString("institution"), rs.getString("startDate"), rs.getString("endDate"), rs.getString("PublicIPAddress")));
                    String ctClassID = rs.getString("classID");
                    String ctClassName = rs.getString("className");
                    String ctAdminID = rs.getString("adminID");
                    String ctinstitution = rs.getString("institution");
                    String ctstartDate = rs.getString("startDate");
                    String ctendDate = rs.getString("startDate");
                    String ctipAddress = rs.getString("endDate");
                    out.println("CDTR S" +  ctClassID + ctClassName + ctAdminID  + ctinstitution + ctstartDate + ctendDate + ctipAddress);
                    StacServ.chatText.append("CDTR " + "S" +  ctClassID + ctClassName + ctAdminID  + ctinstitution + ctstartDate + ctendDate + ctipAddress + "\n");
                    
                    
                }
                
          
          
        }
        
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("ELST")){
          
         
         
          StacServ.chatText.append("ELST TEST " + userName +"\n");
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand + "\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          int userID = dbconnection.getUserID(userName);
          
          ResultSet userClasses = dbconnection.getStudentsClasses(userID);
          String dummy = Integer.toString(userID);
          StacServ.chatText.append("userID is: " +dummy +"\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to find classes for user: " + userName + "\n");
          sb = new StringBuilder("");
                while(userClasses.next()){
                    
                    String ctClassID = userClasses.getString("classID");
                    
                    sb.append(ctClassID);
                    sb.append(" ");
                    
                }
                out.println("ELSR S" +  sb.toString() + "\n");
                StacServ.chatText.append("ELSR S" +  sb.toString() + "\n");
          
          
        }
        
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("CLST")){
          
         
          userName = "ejohn";
          StacServ.chatText.append("ELST TEST " + userName +"\n");
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand + "\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          int userID = dbconnection.getAdminsID(userName);
          
          ResultSet userClasses = dbconnection.getAdminClasses(userID);
          String dummy = Integer.toString(userID);
          StacServ.chatText.append("userID is: " +dummy +"\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attemplting to find classes for user: " + userName + "\n");
           userName = "CCDawg";
          sb = new StringBuilder("");
                while(userClasses.next()){
                    
                    String ctClassID = userClasses.getString("classID");
                    
                    sb.append(ctClassID);
                    sb.append(" ");
                      
                }
                out.println("ELSR S" +  sb.toString() + "\n");
                StacServ.chatText.append("ELSR " + "S " +  sb.toString() + "\n");
          
          
        }
        
        else if(commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("ENRL")){
            System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
            StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
            userName = "CCDawg";
            String flag = "0";
            
            
            String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
            String classID = keys[0];
            String deviceID = keys[1];
            int classIDs = Integer.parseInt(classID);
            dbconnection.addDevice(userName, classIDs, deviceID, flag);
            
        }
        
        else if(commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("CDRP")){
            userName = "PillCosby";
            String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
            String classID = keys[0];
            
            int classIDs = Integer.parseInt(classID);
            dbconnection.unenrollStudent(classIDs, userName);
            
        }
        
        
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("REGA")){
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String uName = keys[0];
          String uPass = keys[1];
          String fName = keys[2];
          String lName = keys[3];
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attempting to add Admin: " + fName + " " + lName);
          dbconnection.createAdmin(uName, uPass, fName, lName);
          out.println("REGA " + "S"+"\n");
          out.flush();
        }
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGA")){
          ResultSet rs = null;
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String uName = keys[0];
          String uPass = keys[1];
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attempting to Login Admin: " + uName+"\n");
          rs =  dbconnection.checkAdmin(uName);
          if(rs != null){
              while(rs.next()){
                  String check = rs.getString(1);
                  if(uName.equals(check)){
                      check = rs.getString(2);
                      if(uPass.equals(check)){
                          StacServ.chatText.append("Admin: " + uName + " logged in."+"\n");
                          out.flush();
                          out.println("LOGR S");
                          userName = uName;
                          out.flush();
                          
                         
                          
                      }
                      else{
                          StacServ.chatText.append("Admin: " + uName + "Incorrect username or password"+"\n");
                          out.flush();
                          out.println("LOGR " + "F"+"\n");
                          out.flush();
                      }
                  }
                  
              }
          }
          else{
              StacServ.chatText.append("Admin: " + uName + "is not registered in the system");
              out.println("LOGA " + "F"+"\n");
              out.flush();
          }
          
        }
        else if (commandName.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGU")){
          ResultSet rs = null;
          System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
          StacServ.chatText.append("Client Says :" + clientCommand+"\n");
          StacServ.chatText.append(restofString +"\n");
          //restofString = restofString.replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", "");
          String[] keys = restofString.split("\"?( |$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\"?");
          String uName = keys[0];
          String uPass = keys[1];
          
          uName = uName.replace("\"", "");
          uPass = uPass.replace("\"", "");
          
          StacServ.chatText.append("Attempting to log in: " + uName+"\n");
          rs =  dbconnection.checkUser(uName);
          if(rs != null){
              while(rs.next()){
                  String check = rs.getString(1);
                  if(uName.equals(check)){
                      check = rs.getString(2);
                      if(uPass.equals(check)){
                          StacServ.chatText.append("User: " + uName + " logged in."+"\n");
                          out.println("LOGR S");
                          userName = uName;
                          
                          out.flush();
                      }
                      else{
                          StacServ.chatText.append("User: " + uName + "\n" + "Incorrect password" +"\n");
                          out.println("LOGR F" + "\n");
                          out.flush();
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          else{
              StacServ.chatText.append("Admin: " + uName + "is not registered in the system");
              out.println("LOGR F");
              out.flush();
          }
          
        }
        else {
          //out.println(clientCommand);
          out.flush();
        }
      }
      
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A good tip would be to reduce the program/code to the point it does only minimal code to reproduce the problem. I guess all the command handlers could be removed and the problem happens before the while? (see answer below in that case)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use an `ObjectOutputStream`?

It will output a serialization header to the underlying `OutputStream`. If you want to avoid that but still have methods for raw data output (which you might not need if you have a line oriented protcol) then a `DataOutputStream` offers the same methods without the serialisation header.

For a line based protocol `StreamWriter` is the better alternative.

Comment: @Yoleaux good to know. I have beautified my answer a bit so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix a `PrintWriter` and an `ObjectOutputStream` on the same socket, and an `ObjectOutputStream` sends a stream header when constructed. It starts with 0xAC though, not 0xFFFD.